# 95 consecutive Full GCs but no OOM. How could that happen?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm troubleshooting a Java web application which runs fine for a while after which the heap suddenly spikes up to 100% and this results in consecutive Full GCs with almost no old gen being cleared out. This however does not result in an OOM with the usual `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` message.
How could this be?

Here are 6 Full GC entries:

```
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37491:2018-05-01T09:10:52.156+0000: 671212.664: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:10:52.156+0000: 671212.664: [CMS: 7077887K->7077887K(7077888K), 28.6425809 secs] 9043967K->9043787K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 28.6428227 secs] [Times: user=28.63 sys=0.00, real=28.64 secs]
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37510:2018-05-01T09:11:20.803+0000: 671241.311: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:11:20.803+0000: 671241.311: [CMS: 7077887K->7077888K(7077888K), 42.8881300 secs] 9043964K->9043856K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 42.8883826 secs] [Times: user=42.85 sys=0.01, real=42.89 secs]
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37529:2018-05-01T09:12:03.694+0000: 671284.201: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:12:03.694+0000: 671284.201: [CMS: 7077888K->7077888K(7077888K), 28.8305893 secs] 9043959K->9043845K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 28.8308264 secs] [Times: user=28.83 sys=0.01, real=28.83 secs]
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37548:2018-05-01T09:12:32.527+0000: 671313.035: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:12:32.527+0000: 671313.035: [CMS: 7077888K->7077887K(7077888K), 34.2235811 secs] 9043967K->9043802K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 34.2238304 secs] [Times: user=34.22 sys=0.00, real=34.23 secs]
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37567:2018-05-01T09:13:06.754+0000: 671347.261: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:13:06.754+0000: 671347.262: [CMS: 7077887K->7077887K(7077888K), 30.2722671 secs] 9043966K->9043854K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 30.2725042 secs] [Times: user=30.27 sys=0.00, real=30.27 secs]
gc_20180423_1443.log.11.current:37586:2018-05-01T09:13:37.028+0000: 671377.536: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-05-01T09:13:37.028+0000: 671377.536: [CMS: 7077887K->7077887K(7077888K), 35.6276778 secs] 9043955K->9043843K(9043968K), [Metaspace: 75140K->75140K(1118208K)], 35.6278998 secs] [Times: user=35.61 sys=0.01, real=35.63 secs]
```

As per my calculations total duration based on the logs for these 6 entries is 164.872s out of which GC takes up 164.8583663s which equals 99.99% time in GC.
Given total heap of 9043968K bring 2% to 180879.36K.

The total heap cleared from the logs in these 5 executions is 679K (across the calls) which is way less than 2% yet there's no OOM thrown.

The `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` flag has not been used.

Here's a list of the GC params:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:CICompilerCount=4 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:GCLogFileSize=10485760 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/WORK/log/solr/solr.hprof 
-XX:InitialHeapSize=9663676416 -XX:LogFile=/WORK/log/solr/vm.log -XX:+LogVMOutput 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=9663676416 -XX:MaxNewSize=2415919104 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 
-XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=196608 -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:NewSize=2415919104
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:OldSize=7247757312
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/WORK/bin/oom.sh solr -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=67108864 -XX:+PrintGC 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=500 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:-UseBiasedLocking 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:+UseParNewGC
```

JDK version is `openjdk-1.8.0_151`

Please let me know if you spot an error in my calculations or my understanding of the  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` rule that error is thrown when more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered.

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide much to go on. Perhaps some class is wildly creating and then quickly releasing instances of something on the heap. GC is continually freeing up the heap, only to have it fill again immediately.

Comment: I'm not yet sure what's causing the heap to get filled up (no pattern can be observed across multiple dumps) but does that matter given that the overhead oom will not depend on some class creating objects wildly but rather the gc times and heap freed?

Comment: What you are describing is a serious problem somewhere in your system. You have to identify the root cause, that is, what is trying to use 98% of the heap in the first place.

Comment: I understand that. It's been extremely difficult to pin down the issues since there's no pattern on the heap and use of better methods with jconsole or jfr is not possible. If the app can somehow oom, it will provide us with the exact stack trace of what blew it up hence my question.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no calls to `System.gc()` from your application? Using the CMS collector, these will (usually) always trigger full GC. Adding `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` will make these calls no-OPs.

Comment: @MickMnemonic 100% sure that there are no `System.gc()` calls.

Comment: Java docs are a bit vague on what the 98% is with respect to, i.e. "Java process" time. It's likely to be possible to fully resource the GC while there remain free cores, so Java process utilization looks much lower than 98%. That's just a guess. Maybe this is helpfull: https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/programmatically-dumping-heap-from-java-applications

Comment: @Gene I guess what you're saying is that GC uses only one core and can be sped up by the use of multiple cores? that's not what i'm looking for because no matter how short the gcs, the app being stuck in the cycle is a problem. I need to know why it won't break out of that cycle.

Comment: *"The -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit flag has not been used."*  Try -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit.  It is possible that the option is turned off by default ... with the other flags you are using.